# Rails default_scope based on some value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Post`. I want to show first posts where `name` is `'esa'` then order by `updated_at`.

I tried this in `post.rb` but doesn't work:

```
default_scope {Post.where(name: 'esa') && order(updated_at: :desc) }
```

Comment: `default_scope` is often discouraged and this use is even more bizarre. Are you positive you want all requests to the `posts` table be filtered and ordered this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be rather ugly, but here it is.

```
default_scope do
  order("CASE WHEN name = 'esa' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END").order(updated_at: :desc)
end
```

Comment: this shows me just post with name esa not other posts..

Comment: @Nda.S because this is how querying works, - it returns you a collection of items that match the criteria you passed, in your particular case to `where` clause

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I want to show me first posts with name esa, and then other post ordered by updated_at

Comment: @NikitaMisharin it worked, thanks!!!